# z3python: no XOR operator?

Tags: z3, z3py

I have this code in Z3 python:

```
x = Bool('x')
y = Bool('y')
z = Bool('z')
z == (x xor y)
s = Solver()
s.add(z == True)
print s.check()
```

But this code reports below error when running:

```
c.py(4): error: invalid syntax
```

If I replace `xor` with `and`, there is no problem. So this means XOR is not supported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `Xor(a, b)`. Moreover, to create the Z3 expression that represents the formula `a and b`, we must use `And(a, b)`. In Python, we can't overload the operators `and` and `or`. 
Here is an example with the `Xor` ([available online at rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/90IR)).

```py
x = Bool('x')
y = Bool('y')
z = Xor(x, y)
s = Solver()
s.add(z)
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

Comment: i find that funny since (x and y) is OK, but (x xor y) is not supported. thanks so much, Leo!

Comment: (x and y) is not building a new Z3 expression. It is not doing what you want. In python, (x and y) evaluates x, if it returns False, then the result is False. Otherwise, it returns the result of evaluating y. Thus, (x and y) evaluates to the Z3 expression y, when x and y are Z3 expressions.